# Alert copied clipboard input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

```
<p id="p1">Hello, I'm TEXT 1</p>

function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

I thought I could do: `alert($temp)`; but it's giving me an error: object Object.

I wanted to alert "the clipboard copied text" in a popup box. 
How can it be done, please?

Comment: So whats wrong with `alert("the clipboard copied text")`? _it's giving me an error_ may be you need `alert($temp.val());`

Comment: "[object Object]" is not an error, it is the string presentation of an object.

Comment: _“How can it be done, please?”_ - use console.log first, log the object to console, and inspect it there. Then you will see what specific _property_ (if any) of the object contains the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function copyToClipboard(elementId) {
        var aux = document.createElement("input");
        aux.setAttribute("value", document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML);
        document.body.appendChild(aux);
        aux.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        console.log("the clipboard copied text :", aux.value);
        alert("the clipboard copied text :" + aux.value);
        document.body.removeChild(aux); 
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this piece of code solves the problem?

Comment: When you pass "p1" id to the "copyToClipboard" function it will alert text inside it

Comment: simplest example you could find on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_oncopy_p